# How does routing work with a feature in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

Let's say I want to use Aurelia's feature... feature, to make a "user" feature to manage users, and I have a different view for the various crud operations. How do I organize the routing for create read update delete? is that done in the feature? is it done in the app? some combination thereof?  please provide an example.

Answer (score 2):

One does not simply add routes through a feature.

However, if you are building a larger application, you can use dependency injection container to expose a "route" object to your application, which features can leverage and extend.

**main.js**

```
import { MyRouteConfig } from 'myRouteConfig';

@inject(MyRouteConfig)
export class App {

    constructor(config) {
        this.routes = config.routes;
    }

    configureRouter(config, router) {
        config.map(this.routes);
    }
}
```

A feature is pulled in through a `configure` function which is passed the Aurelia object. You can use the Aurelia object DI container to get an instance of your `MyRouteConfig` object;

**feature/index.js**

```
import { MyRouteConfig } from '../myRouteConfig';

export function configure(aurelia) {

    let config = aurelia.container.get(MyRouteConfig);
    Array.prototype.push.apply(config.routes, [
        { route: 'feature', moduleId: 'feature/home' },
        { route: 'feature/edit', moduleId: 'feature/edit' }
    ])
}
```

However, **this is not a best practice at all**. It is at best a clever use of the tools and at worst a hack. There are lots of pitfalls to this approach, including difficulty loading the correct module paths and overlapping routes, and you should only use this strategy if you really know what you are doing. That said, it can be done.

Comment: What is the recommended way? I think I'm confused because I have routes into a subdirectory that is not a feature. But I'm thinking about making those features, and trying to figure out how to work with that from a routing perspective.

Comment: if there are routes, than this is likely an integral part of your application. features are like little local plugins, modular. don't use features for integral parts of your application.

Comment: please upvote if this answer helped you, accept if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

**feature/index.js**

```
import { FrameworkConfiguration } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router, RouteConfig } from 'aurelia-router';

export function configure(config: FrameworkConfiguration) {
   var router = config.aurelia.container.get(Router) as Router;
   let newRoute: RouteConfig = {
      route: 'login',
      name: 'login',
      moduleId: 'login/login',
      nav: true,
      title: 'Login'
   };
   router.addRoute(newRoute);
}
```